# Updating table with select sum from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: orders and order_items.I need to update the column xpto_spent on orders table with the sum of the total spent with items of the brand XPTO (items described in order_items table).

My current query is returning timeout from mysql server. The timetou is set to 28800 seconds.

```
UPDATE orders
SET orders.xpto_spent = (
    select 
    format( sum(total), 2) as xpto_spent
    from order_items
    where order_items.brand = "XPTO"
    AND orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
    group by order_items.order_id
);
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Just execute two queries (inside a transaction); one to reset all values to null, and one to update matching values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table `orders` to the query that returns all the sums from `order_items`:

```
UPDATE orders o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, FORMAT(SUM(total), 2) AS xpto_spent
    FROM order_items
    WHERE brand = 'XPTO'
    GROUP BY order_id
) t ON o.order_id = t.order_id
SET o.xpto_spent = t.xpto_spent
```

Comment: Thanks, but the INNER JOIN is not covering all orders from the table orders. Trying LEFT JOIN I'm getting the same timout error.

Comment: The INNER JOIN covers only the orders for which there are rows in order_items. If there aren't any and you want 0 or NULL for that order then you should use LEFT join and maybe COALESCE(). For the timeout error I can't say why.

Answer (score 3):

You would generally do this using `join`, but you can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE orders o
    SET o.xpto_spent = (SELECT SUM(oi.total)
                        FROM order_items oi
                        WHERE oi.brand = 'XPTO' AND
                              oi.order_id = o.order_id
                       );
```

For this query, you want an index on `order_items(order_id, brand, total)`.  That will probably speed your query.

Comment: Thank you, but this query resulted in no changes on orders table.

Comment: @JeffMonteiro . . . All rows should be affected.  If nothing changes, then the sums are already correct.

Comment: Working fine as expected. :)